# PTIJ: Oscar the Grouch getting Tzara'at on his garbage can

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If Oscar the Grouch gets Tzara'at on his garbage can, is that considered Tzara'at of clothing or Tzara'at of one's home?

[image: Oscar the Grouch]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can't be *tsara'at* of a house, because round houses are not subject to *tsara'at*, as we read in [mishna Nega'im 12:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Negaim.12.1?lang=bi).

> ‮כָּל הַבָּתִּים מִטַּמְּאִין בַּנְּגָעִים, חוּץ מִשֶּׁל נָכְרִים. הַלּוֹקֵחַ בָּתִּים מִן הַנָּכְרִים, יֵרָאוּ בַתְּחִלָּה. **בַּיִת עָגֹל, בַּיִת טְרִיגוֹן, בַּיִת הַבָּנוּי בִּסְפִינָה אוֹ בְאַסְקַרְיָא, עַל אַרְבַּע קוֹרוֹת, אֵינוֹ מִטַּמֵּא בַנְּגָעִים.** וְאִם הָיָה מְרֻבָּע, אֲפִלּוּ עַל אַרְבָּעָה עַמּוּדִים, מִטַּמֵּא:
>
> All houses may contract negaim uncleanness, except those of non-Jews. If one bought houses from non-Jews, any it must be inspected as if they had then first appeared. **A round house, a triangular house, or a house built on a ship, on a raft or on four beams, is not susceptible to negaim uncleanness.** But if it was four-sided, even if it was built on four pillars, it is susceptible to uncleanness.

Additionally, only wool, linen, or leather clothing can contract *tsara'at*, as it says in [Leviticus 13:47–48](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.13.47?lang=bi):

> ‮וְהַבֶּ֕גֶד כִּֽי־יִהְיֶ֥ה ב֖וֹ נֶ֣גַע צָרָ֑עַת בְּבֶ֣גֶד צֶ֔מֶר א֖וֹ בְּבֶ֥גֶד פִּשְׁתִּֽים׃ א֤וֹ בִֽשְׁתִי֙ א֣וֹ בְעֵ֔רֶב לַפִּשְׁתִּ֖ים וְלַצָּ֑מֶר א֣וֹ בְע֔וֹר א֖וֹ בְּכָל־מְלֶ֥אכֶת עֽוֹר׃
>
> When an eruptive affection occurs in a cloth of wool or linen fabric, in the warp or in the woof of the linen or the wool, or in a skin or in anything made of skin

But we are assuming that there is *tsara'at*! So what's the solution? In fact, it is *tsara'at* of a house, and the trash can that we see is not the entire house. The trash can leads to a [much larger house](https://muppet.fandom.com/wiki/Oscar%27s_trash_can) (it has contained a swimming pool, a bowling alley, ...), and we must assume that this house is indeed subject to *tsara'at*.

Comment: Yeah, but is Sesame Street in Eretz Yisrael? If not, then the house isn't subject to tzaraas either.

Comment: Sure!  Haven't you heard of Rechov Sumsum in the heart of Jerusalem?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechov_Sumsum

Comment: The quite from Vayikra makes clear that leather clothing can also contract _tsara'at_.  This does not affect the correctness of the answer, for Oscar's garbage can is metal, and not covered by the text.

Comment: @Codes Thanks — I wrote leather originally, and then switched to linen because in a brainfart I thought linen included leather. :-/

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi But then houses in Jerusalem aren't subject to tzaraas either!

Comment: @Meir I think that's a machloket. Rabbi Yehuda says only places with Kedusha (like the Beit haMikdash and synagogues)  in Jerusalem are immune to Tsaraat.

Comment: @DanielKagan True, R' Yehudah does say in Tosefta Negaim 6:1 that "I heard this only about the Beis Hamikdash." (Nothing about synagogues.) Yasher koach for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I’m concerned, the Oscars are pure Tumah.