# PTIJ: If Gary the Snail had Tzara'at, is it considered bodily, clothing, or house?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Similar to another PTIJ question I asked ([PTIJ: Oscar the Grouch getting Tzara'at on his garbage can](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120403/17591)), if Gary the snail from Spongebob had Da'as and became a Ger, but subsequently got Tzara'at on his shell, would that constitute Tzara'at of the body, of one's clothing, or of one's house?

The following points can be argued:

1. One could argue that the snail shell is Batul to the snail, and be considered part of one's guf, thereby being Tzara'at of the body.
2. Or it can be argued that it's like clothing, since there are snails that remove their own shell, and wear it like clothing.
3. Or it can be argued it's like a house, since the snail lives in it.

Additionally, although round houses aren't subject to Tzara'at ([Mishna Nega'im 12:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Negaim.12.1?lang=bi)), some snails have cone-shaped shells.

And there are snails in Israel (Sphincterochila boissieri), ruling out the notion that houses outside Israel aren't subject to Tzara'at.

[image: Gary the Snail]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your last two paragraphs if you're asking specifically about Gary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rashi Devarim 8:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.8.4.1) says that a snail's shell is considered clothing.